# Can Muggles see or enter Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, hogwarts, fantastic-beasts, muggles

Are muggles able to see and/or enter Hogwarts?

Has anything been said or implied in any of the books or films or any of their supporting materials that would support or conflict with Muggles being able to see or enter Hogwarts?

Comment: That suggests that he might be a Squib

Comment: going soley from the trailer, and how Jacob clearly has no idea how to hold the thing, my initial guess is this is just a 'yes, I'm a wizard card' for him to have, since Grindlewald is declaring war on Muggles

Comment: Why did you edit your question to close it as a dupe? The answer to your original film-specific question doesn't exist at the dupe target.

Comment: The answer didn't exist here either (except as a tacked on addendum to a wrong answer), and editing the question to match the answers seemed a lot easier than expecting a new answer to be posted and upvoted to the top.

Comment: @ibid Actually, I was working on an answer based primarily on the films when I came back to find it closed.

Comment: @Obsidia If you still have a draft for that answer, you can post it now. I've rolled back the edit that made the question a dupe and reopened it, since it's reasonable to have a film-specific query posted separately if the [original post (supposed dupe target)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18383/31394) wasn't film-specific and none of its answers include film evidence.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Please don't do that. The answers here are currently focused on the books, and it thus makes a lot more sense to leave this question about the books. If you want a question that's movie specific you're welcome to ask your own instead of invalidating the existing answers.

Comment: No, it's better to leave the existing movie-specific question instead of vandalising it into a duplicate. It's not "invalidating existing answers" to put the question into **the same form it was in when those answers were posted**.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - If your rollback did not invalidate the existing answers, then the question was already a duplicate as it originally written. There's no two ways about it. Either the answers are invalid with the original form, or the original form was a duplicate as well.

Comment: @ibid - This feels dupey now that the dupe answers address this specific question (complete with movie quotes). I'm not sure why you feel that we need two questions that essentially ask the same thing

Comment: Seeing as the question has been determined to also be a dupe in its original form, the only reason previously given against editing this question to the more general case no longer applies, and meta consensus says that this would be a valid edit. I have thus done so, validating the two existing answers.

Answer (score 8):

Throughout the books we're repeatedly told that Muggles cannot visit Hogwarts, in its place they'd see nothing but a derelict ruin with DANGER - DO NOT ENTER signs around it. Presumably its inhabitants would also be hidden from view.

However, there's one instance - albeit only a mention - where we know for a fact that Muggles were able to go to the castle. In Chamber of Secrets, while revisiting Riddle's memory of the night Moaning Myrtle was killed, the then-headmaster Professor Dippet mentions that 'the girl's parents will arrive in the morning'.

In the film it is Riddle who says the line:

> Hagrid. The dead girl's parents will be here tomorrow. The least Hogwarts can do is make sure the thing that killed their daughter is slaughtered.

We know that Myrtle is Muggle-born, her parents are Muggles. How could they visit the castle? It stands to reason that the anti-Muggle enchantments around the school can be modified to allow specific Muggles to enter, or perhaps a spell can be cast on the Muggles themselves to allow them to see through the enchantment.

Comment: A derelict building with "do not enter" signs?  Challenge accepted!

Comment: Or the enchantment only applies outside some radius. Once you actually go inside then you can see everything.

Comment: One possibility is that they might cast a special charm on the Knight Bus to allow them to use it for one time only

Comment: Cooper, there's been some dispute over whether TheLethalCarrot's [edit to your answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/257166/revisions) is too far from your own original post which didn't mention the films at all. You are free to roll back such an edit, if you wish, although note that the question (as originally asked) is specifically looking for a film-based answer, not one just based on the books.

Comment: Note also that both of these events happened well before the events of the main series—there's no indication that the anti-muggle charms have been there for Hogwarts' entire history.

Comment: @Randal'Thor No, I think it's a good addition coupled with the film clip. I'd have added it myself if I had thought of it.

Answer (score 3):

Hogwarts is protected by layers and layers of charms laid by generations of wizards teaching there. So it is quite well protected by a number of them, but in this case there is one specifically designed for the purpose: [Muggle-Repelling Charm](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Muggle-Repelling_Charm)

It is quite ingenious in how it works:

> Every time Muggles have got anywhere near here all year, they've suddenly remembered urgent appointments and had to dash away again.

I think Hermione mentions the specific case of the charm use by Hogwarts when discussing her tent in *Deathly Hallows*, but this may be the *memoriam fragilis est* case.

There are also other charms (as mentioned in other answer), that hides Hogwarts under the illusion of desolate ruin and probably more, but Muggle-repelling charm is probably used all around the perimeter, which I assume is quite large to encompass not only castle but large area nearby, including part of the Forest (if not all, for Muggle protection).