# Has a squib ever played Quidditch?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch, squib

It seems to me like Quidditch doesn't actually require any magical ability (unless that's what makes the brooms fly, but since different brooms have different speeds I assume they're closer to cars than bicycles). Thus, it'd be a great way for a squib to overcome their magical disability, find a well-paying wizard job, and earn the respect of their peers.

Is there any indication in canon of a squib who was able to play Quidditch professionally?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10289/why-can-objects-fly-and-people-other-than-dark-wizards-cant/

Comment: @calccrypto Interesting, so it sounds like you might actually need magical ability to use a broom. That almost seems like enough for an answer.

Comment: Also of note: even if the broom required some magic, squibs *might* be able to use them anyway, just as they can see Hogwarts and magical beasts despite the glamour spells that keep Muggles unaware.

Comment: Related question I just found: [Can Muggles ride broomsticks?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40802/can-muggles-ride-broomsticks/40803#40803) It doesn't seem to have very satisfactory answers though.

Comment: No, but they have [played Rugby](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/scottish-rugby).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No. All signs point to squibs being incapable of using broomsticks, largely based on the Pottermore article describing the [life and times of Angus Buchanan](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/scottish-rugby), bestselling author of *My Life As A Squib*.

**Angus assisted his brothers in their playing of Quidditch, but his involvement was apparently limited to catching snitches *from the ground***

> Angus’s early childhood had been spent dodging curses on an almost
> daily basis, which meant that he was surprisingly fast for a man of
> his size. He found his greatest pleasure and pride in athleticism, and
> soon became adept at the relatively new Muggle sport of rugby. **Years
> of helping his siblings catch Golden Snitches in the back garden also
> made him a natural at cricket.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Scottish Rugby By J.K. Rowling - Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/scottish-rugby)</sup></sub>

**He was incapable of flying a broomstick to Hogwarts, relying on his brother to get him there**

> On the appointed day, **his big brother Hamish took him to Hogwarts on
> the back of his broomstick**, hoping against desperate hope that Angus
> would be allowed to stay once they got there, or that the school might
> be able to tease some magic out of him.
>
> <sub><sup>[Scottish Rugby By J.K. Rowling - Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/scottish-rugby)</sup></sub>

Comment: He could've gained catching practice by catching Snitches on a broom, could he not? There doesn't seem to be anything in the text that implies he was on the ground.

Comment: @TheDarkLord He wouldn't have been very good at cricket if he didn't have practice catching balls standing on the ground, right?

Comment: @TheDarkLord - One plays cricket stood at the crease, not flitting around like Tinkerbell on a flying broom

Comment: @Azor-Ahai. I think he could've. To catch a cricket-ball you need good hand-eye coordination and great reflexes. These are skills you pick up when catching a fast-moving Snitch. I'm not even sure that it would be *possible* to catch a Snitch from ground level. It'd just flutter off above head-height, would it not?

Comment: @Valorum Not if one is playing it the way the gods intended. Also see my other comment.

Comment: well, he wouldn't gain much physical athleticism from flitting around on a broom, would he?

Comment: @thedarklord Well maybe. I was picturing them falling from the sky and him catching them