# Previous winners of The Angus Buchanan Cup for Outstanding Effort in Hogwarts

Tags: harry-potter

I am asking this question based on answer to [Has a squib ever played Quidditch?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152557/has-a-squib-ever-played-quidditch)

> When Angus Buchanan died, he was honoured by both wizarding and Muggle worlds, an almost unique achievement in the annals of history. A shining example of a person who had made the most of the hand that life had dealt them and emerged triumphant, Angus was too modest to realise the impact that he had had. **The Angus Buchanan Cup for Outstanding Effort is awarded at Hogwarts each year** and My Life as A Squib is on its 110th printing.
>
> <sub><sup>**https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/scottish-rugby**</sup></sub>

Do we have any information about who has won The Angus Buchanan Cup for Outstanding Effort? It would be nice to know who won it during Harry's Time in Hogwarts.

Comment: Ungh. What a ridiculous and insulting award. This is like when I was a kid and they tried to give everybody a trophy, and I always won the lame desperate things like "most punctual" or "scholar athlete"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### We don't know

*Scottish Rugby* was written by Rowling in February 2014 as an outlet for her feelings about Scottish Rugby.

> Wizards worldwide support the Scottish rugby team. It's an old magical tradition - for full story, see Pottermore! Please help keep this noble tradition alive by tweeting #wizards4scotlandrugbyteam before #6nations Scotland v Italy tomorrow!
>   <sup><sub>**[Twi](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/436894666500616192)[tter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/436895412038160384)**</sub></sup>

This was the first appearance of the "The Angus Buchanan Cup for Outstanding Effort" in any of Rowling's writings, and seeing as this was the writing that made Angus Buchanan (a contemporary real life figure) into a character of her universe, it is unlikely that the Cup existed in Rowling's mind before this.

In the three years since, Rowling has never mentioned it again. (Maybe tweet her during the next Scottish Rugby match?)