# Can a Muggle get through to Platform 9 & 3/4?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles

Suppose someone from "Harry's world" married a Muggle, and they want to escort their child.
Can the Muggle parent get through to the Hogwarts platform?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10274/who-gets-muggle-born-students-onto-platform-9-3-4?s=6|2.7663

Comment: [Nope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAfi0X-cJag)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sure, absolutely.

Here's Lily's parents on platform nine and three-quarters.

> And the scene refomed. Harry looked around: he was on platform nine and three-quarters, and Snape stood beside him, slightly hunched, next to a thin, sallow-faced, sour-looking woman who greatly resembled him. Snape was staring at a family of four a short distance away. The two girls stood a little apart from their parents. Lily seemed to be pleading with her sister; Harry moved closer to listen.
>
> ...
>
> Lily glanced towards her parents, who were looking around the platform with an air of wholehearted enjoyment, drinking in the scene.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - pp.536-7 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 33, *The Prince's Tale*

Comment: is this scene in the movie?

Comment: @maawneli No, but the films are nonsense ;-)

Comment: @maawneli No, but in the books this is the scene where Petunia first calls Lily a freak (I didn't include it because it's not really relevant), whereas in the movie she calls Lily a freak when Lily is playing with the flower, so that bit kind of makes it into the movie

Comment: I'd be interested to know how - just sort of dragged through the barrier like Kitty Pryde?

Answer (score 0):

Yes because if not how would Hermione have said goodbye to her parents? What did she say goodbye and then walk through a wall? I mean if they can go to Diagon Alley why not Platform 9 3/4?

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! The accepted answer already indicates (with canon proof) that Muggles can pass through the wall, so I don't see what value this answer adds.

Comment: This answer answers the question and adds additional corroborating evidence to the currently accepted answer. However, it would be improved if some evidence, such as quotes, were [edit]ed into it.